# How to run react-native app with hot reload on real ios device?

Tags: ios, react-native, device, livereload

I'm trying to run my react-native app on my iphone with hot reloading
What shall I do?
I've tried different ip's but it crashes

Comment: use expo for this it works perfect on both devices (Android + iOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my IP address to dynamic and now it hot-reloads fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install -g ios-deploy` to install `ios-deploy` library globally.

Then use `react-native run-ios --device "<device name>"` to run your project in your device. Shake the device to get the list of options to enable hot reloading

Comment: It didn’t work for me cause I had a static IP address at my network at first